# Command to list the largest 3 directories/files in my home

Tags: command-line, files

How can I list the largest 3 directories/files which are directly (not recursive) in my home directory using a command?

Comment: you can use `du -a . | sort -nr | head` to list top 10 files or directories based upon size.

Comment: Do you want to recurse into subdirectories of your Home, or do you want the largest 3 folders directly in your home folder? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: Thats is my fault i want largest 3 directories directly found in home folder

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but [ncdu](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) is a pretty amazing tool to use if you want to find out what's using up your disk space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this command which is so fast with respect to other answers

```
du -sm * | sort -nr | head -3
```

Comment: Yes your answer is fast, but hard to guess whether you size is in bytes, kb, mb or gb.. :D Although +1 for fast answer..

Comment: How is this "faster"? And you don't meet your own request - searching in your home directory.

Answer (score 5):

You can use these commands:

```
shopt -s dotglob
du -hs  "$HOME"/* | sort -hr | head -n3
```

Example output:

```
16G     /home/me/.local
455M    /home/me/.minecraft
417M    /home/me/.cache
```

Comment: It goes recursive so that in my case i obtain the same size twice one for the file and one for the directory contains the file.

Comment: `13G /home/maythux/VirtualBox VMs/server/server.vdi
13G /home/maythux/VirtualBox VMs/server`

Comment: @maythux To fix that, just remove the `-a` option. Also, can you raise your queries with my answer in comments instead of in your own answer?

Comment: ok i do it but still taking much time i think that the command i tried is faster.. try yourself

Comment: ok i removed it

Comment: @maythux See my edited answer.

Comment: @maythux: With regards to non recursiveness, I now have a new asnwer.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got a thumb down. This is working fine and also returns the size in Human readable format with **G**, **M** or **K**.

Comment: +1, but I suggest to reset dotglob to its default value after the command.